# Injected JOOQ Context leaks connections

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, jooq, connection-leaks

I use jooq to handle SQL Queries on a PostgreSQL database in an Wildfly web application. The DSLContext is injected via CDI into my beans following the example on http://awolski.com/integrating-jooq-easy/. A bean looks like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private @Inject DSLContext jooq;
    ...
    public boolean update....
        {
        ...
            try {
                jooq.doStuff();    
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getCause().getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                jooq.close();
            }
        ...
        }
```

When I run the application, every connection leaks. What am I missing ?

Comment: regarding the Javadoc, it seems that `DSLContext` does not close the connection if you give it as a constructor parameter, even if you call the close method. It will only close connection that it created itself (giving a String connection url in constructor). So you must close the connection by yourself.

Comment: I see. The constructor was the critical point. Since the documentation on https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.10/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/connection-vs-datasource/ says that jooq will manage the connection and following your help in inspecting the constructor, I found that passing the datasource object instead of the connection object solves the issue :-)

Comment: @MI-Dev: That's right - you could answer your own question here on Stack Overflow. This way, future visitors will see the answer immediately, which is much clearer than reading through the comments.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor was the critical point.

Since the documentation on https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.10/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/connection-vs-datasource/ says that jooq will manage the connection, passing the datasource object instead of the connection object solves the issue:

```
public DSLContext getDSLContext() throws SQLException {
    return DSL.using(ds, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
}
```

in http://awolski.com/integrating-jooq-easy/